# how to replace current process without shell expansion, passing complete ARGV array

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, env

What's the simple equivalent of a Bash

```
exec $0 $*
```

in Ruby?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exec

EDIT

Part of the answer seems to be:

```
  exec( "/bin/ls", *ARGV)  # credits: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/13379
```

So next, will the variable `$0` hold current script's complete name and path, or Ruby binary? Under **irb** only "irb" returns, implying I'd need to find and prepend the path, at least.

Another solution on the fringes comes from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966988/1069375

```
cmd_line = "#{$0} #{ARGV.join( ' ' )}"
```

However, trying `exec cmd_line` seems subject to shell expansion, if it can separate the command from its parameters. 
The `ARGV.join` itself would cram all the arguments together as one.

Comment: This old post from 2001 echos the question: http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/13377

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should execute the current file without invoking a subshell:

```
exec([ File.absolute_path(__FILE__), __FILE__ ], *ARGV)
```

EDIT: Of course, it breaks if you're changing the current working directory in your script.  That is easy to work around, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try  `exec("./#{$0}", *ARGV)` to not worry about the multiple-arguments-crammed-into-one effect.